# possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_FAILURE

Tags: openssl, automake, autoreconf

Trying to create an OpenSSL engine based on a demo code which is an example of [MD5 engine](https://github.com/engine-corner/Lesson-2-A-digest). The `readme` file says that i have to use the following commands in order to build the engine:

```
$ autoreconf -i
$ ./configure
$ make
```

So far so good. The problem is that when I'm executing `autoreconf -i` an error is generated:

```
configure.ac:18: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_FAILURE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I have to mention that I have installed all the needed tools (autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config) and I exhausted all the results on the first page in Google search.
If I'm using the command `autoreconf -vi`, the error doesn't show up, but the Makefile is not generated so I can't complete the build process.
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, OpenSSL version is 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014.
What I'm doing wrong? What is the problem?

Comment: OpenSSL does not use Autotools and friends. They have their own build system. See [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: One of the easiest examples of an ENGINE is Intel's RDRAND engine located at [`<openssl src>/crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c`](http://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unfortunately common problem with autoconf, where the error is reported for the wrong macro. The easy thing to do is to look for the most-recent macro called before `AC_MSG_FAILURE`, which in the linked code would be `AX_CHECK_OPENSSL`.

`AX_` prefix is used by [Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) macros, which gives you an idea where to find it.

I would suggest creating a `m4` directory in repository of the engine and copying the right macro file from acarchive into it, then use `autoreconf -fi -I m4` to have it look for the macro file there.